# Node.js & Gulp: Real piping sequence could differ from written '.pipe()'s chain?

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, nodejs-stream

In the below code, `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass()` will be called before `console.log('intercepted!');` execution. Also, in `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass(targetFileAbsolutePath)`, parameter `targetFileAbsolutePath` will be `undefined`:

```
let currentSourceFileAbsolutePath;

return gulp.src(entryPointsSourceFilesPathsOrGlobs)

    // "gulpPlugins.intercept" is "gulp-intercept"
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.intercept( sourceVynilFile => {
      console.log('intercepted!');
      currentSourceFileAbsolutePath = sourceVynilFile.path;
      console.log(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath); // OK here
      return sourceVynilFile;
    }))

    // "gulpPlugins.if" is "gulp-if"
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.if(
        // currentSourceFileAbsolutePath is undefined !!!
        fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath),
        gulpPlugins.sass()
    ));

// ...

fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass(targetFileAbsolutePath) {

    console.warn('---');
    console.warn(targetFileAbsolutePath); // undefined!

    const targetFilenameExtension = Path.extname(targetFileAbsolutePath);
    let targetFilenameExtensionIsSupportedBySassPreprocessor = false;

    for (const filenameExtension of SUPPORTED_FILENAME_EXTENSIONS__SASS_PREPROCESSOR) {
      if (filenameExtension === targetFilenameExtension) {
        targetFilenameExtensionIsSupportedBySassPreprocessor = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    return targetFilenameExtensionIsSupportedBySassPreprocessor;
}
```

Really, original code written in TypeScript, but I rewrite it to JavaScript to allow more people to understand the code. I said about it because TypeScript compiler somehow understood, what in `pipe(gulpPlugins.if(/*...*/))`, parameter `currentSourceFileAbsolutePath` is not initialized, so `TS2454: Variable 'currentSourceFileAbsolutePath' is used before being assigned.` error occurred.

I am confused because I have similar task which works without error (in right sequence):

```
let currentSourceFileAbsolutePath: string;

return gulp.src(entryPointsSourceFilesPathsOrGlobs)

    .pipe(gulpPlugins.intercept(sourceVynilFile => {
      currentSourceFileAbsolutePath = sourceVynilFile.path;
      return sourceFile;
    }))

    .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.intercept(compiledHtmlFile => {
      // currentSourceFileAbsolutePath is NOT undefined!
      if (shouldValidateCompiledHtmlRespectiveToSourceFile(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath)) {
        HtmlValidator.validateHtml(compiledHtmlFile);
      }
      return compiledHtmlFile;
    }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(() => (
      // currentSourceFileAbsolutePath is NOT undefined!
      getOutputDirectoryForPreprocessedMarkupEntryPointFileByRespectiveSourceFile(currentSourceFileAbsolutePath)
    )));
```

What wrong in the first task? I missed some async call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gulp, by itself, does not reorder what goes through subsequent calls to `.pipe`. I'm not sure what is going on exactly in your case, but your code is **unnecessarily brittle**.

Consider this pattern:

```
gulp.src("...")
  .pipe(pluginA)
  .pipe(pluginB)
```

And suppose that `pluginA` just prints to the console `pluginA` and `pluginB` just prints to the console `pluginB`. You might think that the output would be:

```
pluginA
pluginB
pluginA
pluginB
pluginA
...
```

In other words, each file will go through `pluginA` and then this file will go through `pluginB`, then the next file will go through `pluginA`, etc. That is, `pluginA` won't see a new file until `pluginB` has processed the previous file that `pluginA` has finished processing. Though there are cases in which this order is exactly what will happen, **for the general case this order is not guaranteed**. You can just as well have:

```
pluginA 
pluginA 
pluginA 
pluginB 
pluginA 
pluginB 
pluginB 
pluginB
pluginA 
...
```

The files must be seen by `pluginA` first, but there's no guaranteed that `pluginB` will process a file before `pluginA` gets to its next file.

Your code works fine if the processing order *happens* to be perfectly interleaved like the first example I gave above. But in general, this order is not guaranteed, and your code will fail.

It so happens that **the brittle part of your code is unnecessary**. It is not necessary to record the file's path in a variable outside the file stream and then read it in a later part of the stream. `gulp-if` will pass the file it tests to the condition you give to it. Here is an example:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const gulpIf = require("gulp-if");
gulp.task("default", () =>
          gulp.src("src/**")
          .pipe(gulpIf((file) => {
            console.log(file.path);
            return file.basename === "a";
          }, gulp.dest("out"))));
```

This task will put in the `out` subdirectory all files whose basename is `"a"`. You'll also see on the console the absolute path of each file that passes through the condition given to `gulpIf`.

You could modify `fileShouldBePreprocessedBySass` to accept a Vinyl file and just check `file.path` there instead of saving it and then retrieving it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Got about "order is not guaranteed", and agree that maybe my code is brittle.  However, I really need to know source file absolute path inside pipeline, because in real project logic is more complicated, and it's easier to make decisions based on source file absolute path. Once file pass `.pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())`, filename extension will change to `.html`, and making decision become harder. Reconstruct initial file absolute path is hard too, and also logic will differ depending on concrete task. Any recommended patterns where possible to remember source file?